# Update Multiple JSON Nodes With A JOIN

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have a stored procedure that takes a JSON parameter `@ChangeSet` as below.

```
DECLARE  @ChangeSet varchar(MAX) = 
'{
    "Acts":
    [
        {"ActId":100,"ActText":"Intro","ActNumber":1},
        {"ActId":0,  "ActText":"Beginning","ActNumber":2},
        {"ActId":0,  "ActText":"Middle","ActNumber":3},
        {"ActId":0,  "ActText":"End","ActNumber":4},
    ]
 }';
```

Within the proc, I have a `MERGE` statement that updates tables based on whether it is an `INSERT` (if `ActId` is `0`) or an `UPDATE`. I would like to update the JSON `@ChangeSet` variable with the multiple PK ActId's returned from the `INSERTED` table from the `MERGE` so that I can return it in an `OUT` parameter.

```
ActId   Type    Action  Value       ActNumber
---------------------------------------------
100     Act     UPDATE  Intro       1
101     Act     INSERT  Beginning   2
102     Act     INSERT  Middle      3
103     Act     INSERT  End         4
```

I could re-query the database, outputting as JSON but am interested in a figuring out a technique directly updating the JSON using something like `JSON_MODIFY`, etc. if possible.

I looked at various samples but have not found anything similar. Anybody have any good examples?

Comment: What is your SQL Serve version and what is the final (updated) `@ChangeSet` JSON content? Thanks.

Comment: Any version is ok. The final JSON is the input JSON with the ActId values updated with the pk Identity for the newly inserted records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have two options:

- Modify the `Acts` JSON array using `JSON_MODIFY` (but you need SQL Server 2017+ to use a variable as a path expression). This approach sets a local variable in a `SELECT` statement, so yo must not use `ORDER BY` or `DISTINCT` in the statement.
- Parse the input JSON, use a set-based approach to get the expected results as a table and output the table content as JSON using `FOR JSON AUTO`

JSON:

```
DECLARE @ChangeSet varchar(MAX) = 
'{
    "Acts":
    [
        {"ActId":100,"ActText":"Intro","ActNumber":1},
        {"ActId":0,  "ActText":"Beginning","ActNumber":2},
        {"ActId":0,  "ActText":"Middle","ActNumber":3},
        {"ActId":0,  "ActText":"End","ActNumber":4}
    ]
}';
```

Statement with `JSON_MODIFY`:

```
SELECT @ChangeSet = JSON_MODIFY(
   @ChangeSet,
   CONCAT('$.Acts[', j1.[key], '].ActId'), 
   v.[Id]
)   
FROM OPENJSON(@ChangeSet, '$.Acts') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (ActNumber int '$.ActNumber') j2
JOIN (VALUES 
   (100, 'Act', 'UPDATE', 'Intro',     1),
   (101, 'Act', 'INSERT', 'Beginning', 2),
   (102, 'Act', 'INSERT', 'Middle',    3),
   (103, 'Act', 'INSERT', 'End',       4)
) v ([Id], [Type], [Action], [Value], [ActNumber]) ON v.[ActNumber] = j2.[ActNumber]
```

Statement with `FOR JSON`:

```
SELECT @ChangeSet = (
   SELECT v.[Id] AS ActId, j.ActText, j.ActNumber
   FROM OPENJSON(@ChangeSet, '$.Acts') WITH (
      ActId int '$.ActId',
      ActText varchar(50) '$.ActText',
      ActNumber int '$.ActNumber'
   ) j
   JOIN (VALUES 
      (100, 'Act', 'UPDATE', 'Intro',     1),
      (101, 'Act', 'INSERT', 'Beginning', 2),
      (102, 'Act', 'INSERT', 'Middle',    3),
      (103, 'Act', 'INSERT', 'End',       4)
   ) v ([Id], [Type], [Action], [Value], [ActNumber]) ON v.[ActNumber] = j.[ActNumber]
   FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT ('Acts')
)
```

Result:

```
{
    "Acts":
    [
        {"ActId":100, "ActText":"Intro", "ActNumber":1},
        {"ActId":101, "ActText":"Beginning", "ActNumber":2},
        {"ActId":102, "ActText":"Middle", "ActNumber":3},
        {"ActId":103, "ActText":"End", "ActNumber":4}
    ]
}
```

Comment: SQL 2017 is fine. The Id record should update the ActId for the newly inserted records. I will update the question to make that more clear. 

The other thing is that I need to use the INSERTED table dynamically, not as hard-coded values. This points me in the right direction. Which of the 2 approaches do you favor?

Comment: @WillC OK. Use `JOIN inserted` instead of `JOIN (VALUES (...))` to build the correct statement. Well, about the approach, probably the second one. But you should also measure the performance. Thanks.

Comment: The first answer returned an error: "The argument 2 of the "JSON_MODIFY" must be a string literal." The second worked fine.

Comment: @WillC You are probably using SQL Server 2016 for this test. You need at least SQL Server 2017 to use a variable (or expression) for the second argument of `JSON_MODIFY()`

Comment: I am using 2016, but will upgrade and re-test.

Comment: Worked great with 2017. I am more of a c# guy so I had missed that change. The first example works better for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness with the question, here is the finished routine that takes the Output of a Merge statement, inserts it into a temp table variable, then updates the input JSON with the newly inserted ActId primary keys so that it can then returned by a procedure OUT variable.

```
-- SQL 2017+ REQUIRED

DECLARE @ActActions  table( [ActId] int, [Action] varchar(30),
                     [Value] nvarchar(max), [ActNumber] int );

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

OUTPUT   COALESCE (INSERTED.ActId, DELETED.ActId), $action, 
         COALESCE (INSERTED.ActText, DELETED.ActText),
         COALESCE (INSERTED.ActNumber, DELETED.ActNumber)
INTO    @ActActions;   -- Required semi-colon at end of MERGE

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT  @ChangeSetJson = JSON_QUERY(JSON_MODIFY( 
        @ChangeSetJson, '$.Acts[' + j1.[key] + '].ActId', a.[ActId] )  )
FROM    OPENJSON(@ChangeSetJson, '$.Acts') j1 CROSS APPLY 
        OPENJSON(j1.[value])
        WITH (ActNumber int '$.ActNumber') j2 INNER JOIN
        @ActActions a
            ON a.[ActNumber] = j2.[ActNumber]
WHERE  a.[Action] = 'INSERT'
```